# POS for .NET Scanner: Handling Binary Data

Tags: c#, .net, pos, pos-for-.net, honeywell

If a barcode contains binary data, how would I be able to read the data using the Scanner's DataEvent?

When I read from ScanDataLabel, I get extra 0s between data bytes in some parts of the array while the others seem to be untouched. I have tried encoding them to ASCII and Unicode to no avail.

I am using a Honeywell 1900 handheld barcode scanner for this application.

Below is the code that I attempted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var explore = new PosExplorer();
            var devices = explore.GetDevices(DeviceType.Scanner);
            var device = explore.GetDevice(DeviceType.Scanner, "POSScanner");
            var scan = (Scanner)explore.CreateInstance(device);
            scan.Open();
            scan.Claim(500);
            scan.DeviceEnabled = true;
            scan.DataEventEnabled = true;
            scan.DecodeData = true;
            
            scan.DataEvent += delegate (object sender, DataEventArgs e){
                
                var data = scan.ScanDataLabel;
                var type = scan.ScanDataType.ToString();
                var encoder = Encoding.Unicode;
                var dataString = encoder.GetString(data);
                var rawData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
            };
            Console.ReadLine();
            scan.DeviceEnabled = false;
            scan.Release();
            scan.Close();
        }
```

The data should be, for example

```
{220,3 ...
```

but instead contains

```
{220,0,3,0 ...
```

and the attempted code above has the below, which is incorrect

```
{120,...
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Code has been added to explain what I attempted to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using `Lagacy COM Interop` to run OPOS service objects.
[POS for .NET Architecture (POS for .NET v1.12 SDK Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/bb429017(v=winembedded.11))
[Integration of Legacy Service Objects (POS for .NET v1.12 SDK Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/bb429016(v=winembedded.11))

The `ILegacyControlObject.BinaryConversion` setting described in this article is relevant.
[PosPrinter PrintMemoryBitmap throws illegal exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67711679/9014308)

You may want to set `ILegacyControlObject.BinaryConversion` to `Nibble` or `Decimal` before reading the `ScanData` or `ScanDataLabel` properties of the scanner, and set it to `None` after reading.

However, it is assumed that Honeywell's OPOS service object supports the `BinaryConversion` specification.

And the read data is binary data of `byte[]`, you can handle it as it is, and you do not need to `Encoding.GetBytes`.